# PostMessage and SendMessage WM_SETCURSOR, WM_LBBUTTONDOWN/UP etc all send xPox0, yPos0

Tags: c#, objective-c, winapi, postmessage

I'm writing a C# program to send clicks from a window to another. I'm using SendMessage and PostMessage from the winapi. SendMessage works fine for keyboard events but when I try using it to send mouse events its always sending mouse coordinates 0,0. I can verify with spy++ that the application is receiving the events but the x and y are at (0,0) and the app thinks the mouse is offscreen NCHITTEST=NOTCLIENT.

The code is as follows:

```
PostMessage(appWin, (int)WMessages.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, MakeDword(300, 200));
```

Where PostMessage is declared as:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA", SetLastError = true)]
protected static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, long wParam, long lParam);
```

Where appWin is the handle to the window(verified with spy++ that its receiving the events).
The window has no controls at all. 
I've also tried multiple macros MakeLParam, MakeDword, done it by hand, etc. 
I'm using Windows7.

I spent most of last night/this morning away trying to find the problem but I have not been able to. While there are many posts online regarding Post/SendMessage, I was only able to find one where the similar problem came up and there were no answers.

To summarize the problem:
Does anyone know why SendMessage would be sending the proper message to the application window but instead of passing it the x and y coordinates given its always passing (0,0)?

Thanks!

Comment: Faking input isn't easy. Sometimes you can get it to work with SendMessage/PostMessage, but often that fails.

What you are meant to do is to call `SendInput()`, or perhaps the easier to use `mouse_event()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but SendInput() and mouse_event() both take control of the real mouse by injecting events into the device queue. I need the real mouse to stay unaffected. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: No I do not have any more ideas.  Are you prepared for the possibility that what you are attempting won't work?

Comment: If you're saying have I considered the possibility that it is impossible to do then the answer is no. If you mean have I thought of the possibility that I won't have the right skills to figure it out, then I'd have to say I remain optimistic seeing as injecting keyboard input is working and I think the issue here is one that is simple to spot/resolve for someone who has the experience. I'm hoping someone like that here will be kind enough to lend me a hand.

Comment: I think it's possible that it won't be possible without `SendInput`. What's the target app?  What are you trying to do with faked input? Perhaps there's another way to meet your goal. I don't imagine that your ultimate goal is to fake input. You've probably got a rather more prosaic objective!

Comment: The goal is to make a framework for automating office work, right now I'm testing on notepad. The idea is to load a bunch of xml files and the app would do menial tasks on third party apps based on the schema simultaneously. The reason SendInput won't work is because if its trying to work on multiple files at the same time the mouse/keyboard will be all over the place. Also the third party apps could be minimized, etc. I'm thinking of injecting dll's into every app but there's gotta be a way to make it work without hacking it up so badly.

Comment: Surely you could do it programmatically rather than faking input? Your approach sounds pretty flaky.

Comment: Programatically in what sense? I don't see many other options to interact with 3rd party apps that have no APIs for this kind of interaction. What do you suggest?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I have LBUTTONDOWN/UP commented out right now, they're all experiencing the same thing. Your VM comment intrigues me, since I'm testing in a VM, is there anything I should do differently in a VM? Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can finally see what's wrong with your code.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "PostMessageA", SetLastError = true)] 
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, long wParam, long lParam);
```

The issue is that `long` is 64 bits wide in C#. In a 32 bit process this is incorrect since those parameters should be 32 bits wide.  I would have expected you to have seen a stack imbalance warning when run through the debugger.

The correct declaration is:

```
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

You most definitely don't need to switch to native C++ code to get this to work.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, going to give it a test right now and let you know.

Comment: Hey, I don't have enough rep to vote you up but your answer is right on point. I retested with the following code:
`SendMessage(hWndFour, (uint)WMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, (IntPtr)MAKELPARAM(10, 10));`

where: 
`[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lparam);`

And its working fine. Thanks for the help

Comment: Even if you can't vote up you can accept. Make the tick next to the top of the answer go green.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer to my own question because there were comments made to the effect that it might be impossible to do.

Im not sure why it doesn't work in C#, maybe a typing/casting issue, maybe an issue with the way it handles the lparam. In any case, I wrote the same code in c++ and made it a dll so now I call the function from the dll with the control handler and the input and it sends the input to the proper controls. Using the windows api directly through c++ works fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: FWIW the reason I thought it might be impossible to do with `PostMessage` is that some apps will use information from the message that is only available when the message has been generated by `SendInput`.

Comment: Ah, I see. That would have been more of a case of the application receiving the proper messages but not responding to them. In this case the message was never being properly sent (x,y=0 at all times).

Comment: yes that's right. I'm afraid I was very very slow to pick up on the `long` thing. It's hard keeping all the nuances of these different languages at the front of your brain. I never write C# anyway so that's especially hard.

Comment: Same here, this is my first time writing in C#, I figured it was time for something new. I like it so far but the managed/unmanaged deal is getting really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to inject mouse input with PostMessage/SendMessage, for the same reasons as emist. One important gotcha that has been left out here is that C# applications (or maybe just WPF ones) require the [uiAccess=true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) flag to be set in it's application manifest. Otherwise, messages are never really sent. Also, there are a [Authenticode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms537364%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) hurdles to go through to allow this, and visual studio will refuse to run the debug, but you can attach the debugger to a running process. Hope this helps anyone who come's by this thread.